# Invalid JSON String that extracted from HTML

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have extracted JSON String from HTML code. when i insert that part into [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com) it says it valid JSON. but when i try to validate it from code it says its Invalid

String that extracted from HTML

`[{"shortid":"456673","url":"https://www.google.com","thumb":"https://www.google.com","imgid":"1:00z0z_5mLB7aZ1QcW"},{"shortid":"456673","url":"https://www.google.com","thumb":"https://www.google.com","imgid":"1:00z0z_5mLB7aZ1QcW"},{"shortid":"456673","url":"https://www.google.com","thumb":"https://www.google.com","imgid":"1:00z0z_5mLB7aZ1QcW"},{"shortid":"456673","url":"https://www.google.com","thumb":"https://www.google.com","imgid":"1:00z0z_5mLB7aZ1QcW"},{"shortid":"456673","url":"https://www.google.com","thumb":"https://www.google.com","imgid":"1:00z0z_5mLB7aZ1QcW"},{"shortid":"456673","url":"https://www.google.com","thumb":"https://www.google.com","imgid":"1:00z0z_5mLB7aZ1QcW"},{"shortid":"456673","url":"https://www.google.com","thumb":"https://www.google.com","imgid":"1:00z0z_5mLB7aZ1QcW"},{"shortid":"456673","url":"https://www.google.com","thumb":"https://www.google.com","imgid":"1:00z0z_5mLB7aZ1QcW"},{"shortid":"456673","url":"https://www.google.com","thumb":"https://www.google.com","imgid":"1:00z0z_5mLB7aZ1QcW"},{"shortid":"456673","url":"https://www.google.com","thumb":"https://www.google.com","imgid":"1:00z0z_5mLB7aZ1QcW"},{"shortid":"456673","url":"https://www.google.com","thumb":"https://www.google.com","imgid":"1:00z0z_5mLB7aZ1QcW"},{"shortid":"456673","url":"https://www.google.com","thumb":"https://www.google.com","imgid":"1:00z0z_5mLB7aZ1QcW"}]`

```
let jsonData = extractedString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

if JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(jsonData!) {
    print("Valid Json")
} else {
    print("InValid Json")
}
```

Comment: The declaration is `isValidJSONObject(_ obj: Any)`, `Any` and not `Data` because it can be a Dict or an Array. If it was only meant for `Data`, it would have been specified.

Comment: what do you mean by if it was only meant for Data? im not clear

Comment: An object of class `Data`. But nevermind.